# Error 411 on pushing nuget package to Nuget.Server

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I have successfully setup Nuget.Server from http://nugetserver.net.
I can access http://localhost/ site and http://localhost/nuget/Packages. 
Unfortunately, every `nuget push` causes the following error:

```
Pushing Sample.1.1.0.nupkg to 'http://localhost/api/v2/package'...
  PUT http://localhost/api/v2/package/
  LengthRequired http://localhost/api/v2/package/ 33ms
Kod stanu odpowiedzi nie wskazuje powodzenia: 411 (Length Required).
```

It looks like nuget client is not setting `Content-Length` header so IIS is complaining. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case it was because of being behind a proxy. The proxy would just not forward all the info. Once the proxy removed the server would accept put request normally.

Comment: Indeed, after investigating requests with Wireshark it turned out that proxy was cutting of some request's data like part do header. Don't know why, but changing to another proxy helped.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same error `411 (Length required)`, and my problem was that I set `-src https://nuget.org` but this is wrong, it needs to be `-src https://www.nuget.org`.

Comment: Great answer, you just saved my day. Thank you for sharing.